# Запятая. Уместна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> *Потом будут прогулки и чаяпитие(,) и всё.*

Здравствуйте, возможна ли в данном месте запятая? А тире? Нужны вообще ли здесь запятые?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант записи (зависит от контекста):

***Потом будут прогулки и чаепитие, и это всё.***

Затруднительно говорить о правильности построения предложения и постановки знаков, если смысл предложения до конца неясен.

**Дополнение**

Конечно, уместно спросить: **по какому правилу** мы ставим здесь знаки?

Предложение **"это всё"** рассматривается как отдельное простое предложение (это — подлежащее, всё — сказуемое).

Для присоединения этого предложения к первой части можно использовать как **союзную, так и бессоюзную связь.** При наличии союза И ставим запятую (ССП), а при отсутствии союза  ставим тире (БСП).

Выбор подходящего варианта делается **по контексту.**

Comment: «И всё» — в значении только это и ничего больше. То есть «это всё» тоже подходит

Comment: Можно и так написать:  "Потом будут прогулки и чаепитие — это всё".  Форма записи от стиля текста и его содержания зависит. Смотрите по слуху, что лучше походит.